# Doctrine fetch eagrly does not keep track of referenced entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine 2.7 with unbuffered query, due to very large result set. I want to query an entity with a relation to another entity (many to one). My code looks something like this:

```php
    $em = new EntityManager();
    $queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder
        ->select(Employee::class)
        ->from(…)
        ->where(…)
        ->setParameter(…);
    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
    $query->setFetchMode(Employee::class, 'department', ClassMetadataInfo::FETCH_EAGER);
    foreach ($query->iterate() as $row) {
        yield $row[0];
        $em->clear();
    }
```

Unfortunately, the Department entity is not being loaded on each iteration. I expect it to be loaded since I use `FETCH_EAGER`. So for example when I call an inner method of `Department`, e.g. `Department->getId()`, I get an error like this: `Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.`.

I found a bypass, which is to use the deprecated method `$em->detach()` instead of `$em->clear()`. I assume this only detaches the `Employee` entity but not the `Department`. But if the `Department` should be fetched on each iteration, why does `$em->clear()` not working?

I would like to understand the mechanism, and not just to have something to copy-paste into my code.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `asUnbuffered` and cannot find any documentation on that. Is that really a Doctrine method or are you working with a subclass?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It is indeed a subclass. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to build a `JOIN` query that builds rows from both Employee and Department, so your department data is accessible from `$row`? From the sample provided you're not really doing anything with Employee and Department as independent entities, you just need both their data for output.

i'm not deeply familiar with Doctrine so i don't want to attempt sample code that will be incorrect and misleading. However, Doctrine's docs look pretty solid:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.11/reference/query-builder.html#join-clauses

Comment: Yes, that would be a possibility. The problem is no longer an issue by the way, but I still want to understand why does Doctrine behave the way it does.

Comment: @noam - Semi-educated guess: "eager" loads query once for primary entity (Employee), then separate queries for relations (Department, etc.). You might be expecting all the eager loads *prior* to the iteration, but that would defeat the purpose of being unbuffered. Only when the Employee entity is loaded will it eager-fetch for *that* Employee, incurring the queries that try to step on your unbuffered connection. Seem reasonable? If i'm way off, my apologies.

Comment: I expect one query per line: Employess + Department. It is almost certainly the case, except that when I call `$em->clear()` the Department is being detached and never loaded again... Which is what I tried to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think that behavior come because of your operation order. I mean you **yield** first but didn't cleared entitymanager yet. Just try to rearrange them like this:

```
foreach ($query->iterate() as $row) {
    $result = $row[0];
    $em->clear();
    yield $result;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? I tried it and there is no difference

Comment: I've tried it just now. No errors at all. What kind of error did you got?

Comment: Same as in my original post: `Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.`